# When to use more than one Sammy.js application?

Tags: sammy.js

As I'm learning about Sammy.js I read that you can have several Sammy.js applications in the same page, each bound to a different element (i.e. div). I would like to understand why would this be useful.

I read in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899335/why-does-sammy-js-never-use-post-route) that only forms inside a bound element will trigger the route change, I'm thinking this could be used to modularize your application. Is there another use case beside this? Could you provide an example of how to modularize your application in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We implemented a component similar to Sammy in our Silverlight application some time ago. The similarity is in that both represent a kind of a simple browser that can be bound to a UI region. The approach gave us several benefits:

1. We had an extensible way to add new content implementations. I mean that we could add plugins to our app that contained new forms/views which the application core had no knowledge about.
2. We could easily implement composite views, e.g. dashboard that were able to show any view implemented in any module. Including themselves. (A-ha, we had created recursive dashboards that worked until the app hit the memory limit. Kind of Inception. :))

Sammy can be used to reach these goals as well.

However, you must understand that from all Sammy applications running on a page, only one can be bound to the browser location bar. Others will have their location visible only to javascript, or you'll need to render location bars for them on the page.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about the complexity added to routing when several modules needed to keep their history/state in their own URLs, I guess some convention with prefixes for url parameters or something similar could be implemented.

Comment: @JuanCampa In some cases you are fine without linking application objects for different levels. If you need to link them together and to the browser location bar, having hierarchical URLs that reflect the application objects hierarchy is a good approach. You can then split the routing into multiple steps along the hierarchy: the top-level application object routes the first part of the URL, then comes the next level application object and so on. I haven't done that, but it looks pretty clear and should work.